# getsockname() shows 127.0.0.1 after connect() to public IP

Tags: sockets, loopback, winsock2

I'm struggling to make sense of this. The issue is seen on a machine that is:

- Remote (I do not have access to it)
- Running Windows 7
- NOT running a proxy or VPN (or so I have been told)

My application has a snippet of code that tries to quickly determine which interface the OS prefers. It does the following:

```
// Create a socket
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);

// Resolve DNS query
DWORD dwRemoteIp = GetHostAddr("www.google.com")
// I've simplified the call here, but "www.google.com" resolves to 172.217.3.100 in host byte order, so the resolution is correct

// Create the remote address to connect to
sockaddr_in remoteaddr = {0};
remoteaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
remoteaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(dwRemoteIp);
remoteaddr.sin_port = htons(80);

// Connect the socket
if (0 == connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, sizeof(remoteaddr))) {

    // The connection succeeded -- see which local address was bound to
    sockaddr_in localaddr = {0};
    int len = sizeof(localaddr);
    if (0 == getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&localaddr, (socklen_t *)&len)) {

        // Here is where I see dwLocalIp == 0x7F000001, or 127.0.0.1
        DWORD dwLocalIp = ntohl(localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    }
}
```

What could be going on here?